# Can't remove lockring

Tags: shimano, hub, cassette

Have been trying to get the lockring removed from my cassette so I can replace it with a spacer kit and one sprocket (singlespeed conversion). I managed to get it loose, although the wrong way - so the whole cassette started unscrewing off the hub. I can't turn it the other way at all. Can someone confirm:

1. That this is actually a lockring
2. If so, any tips on how to remove it?

I have a chain whip, lockring tool and 24mm spanner/wrench.

[image: cassette]

Comment: Are you sure that is a cassette?  It looks like a freewheel to me.  If the whole thing is unscrewing then that is what a freewhell does.    http://sheldonbrown.com/free-k7.html

Comment: The hub is threaded and the cassette screws on, so I'm lost...

Comment: It looks like a Shimano MF-TZ something. put the model number into google and you'll find that its a freewheel, and you need a Freewheel remover like the Park tool FR 1.2. Do you have a chain tensioner/horizontal dropouts/eccentric hub/bb to make the singlespeed conversion even possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it screws on then it is a freewheel not a cassette.  They are not the same.  There is a link in my comment.

Your spacer kit with one sprocket was probably for cassette / freehub.  It is not going to work.

I suspect you can find a freewheel single speed conversion.
You need a single speed freewheel - not a sprocket and a lockring.

Comment: Do I need a SS freewheel and lockring?

Comment: What part of "You need a single speed freewheel - not a sprocket and a lockring" is not clear?  I don't know how to be any more clear.  You have a freewheel - not a cassette.  A freewheel does not have a lockring.

Comment: One question at a time.

Answer (score 0):

This is a freewheel, not a cassette, and thus it has no lockring.  It does have the ability for a skilled and careful mechanic to disassemble and replace bearings, to rebuild it.  However, it is cheaper to simply replace it.

Answer (score -2):

take a sparkplug  3/4 make sure that the back willfit inside the freewheel of the cog and no axle is there it might need a little hammer tap to get the six sided part down in there make sure u dont mind scratching outside of socket then u need a pipe wrench or good table vise and grip socket turning wheel counter clockwise for it to thread off the hub..

Comment: ... or just spend 5 dollars on a freewheel tool ...

Comment: Welcome to Bicycles SE. We ask that you [write to the best of your ability](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) on this site. This means proper capitalization, proper punctuation, and complete sentences. As your answer stands, it is very difficult to read, especially for people who speak English as a second language. Please edit it so that it will be more clear for our global audience. Otherwise, the community is likely to downvote it and it may ultimately be deleted.

Comment: I'm sorry but there are special tools to remove freewheels and cassettes and not using them is just asking for trouble. Especially when, in the next, breath, you're advocating hammering things. These things are built to be screwed and unscrewed, not to be bludgeoned.